# how svg matrixTransform and svg.getScreenCTM works?

Tags: svg, transform

```
    var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
    pt.x = evt.clientX;
    pt.y = evt.clientY;
    var globalPoint = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
```

someone can explain to me how the matrixTransform works in this case. thanks

Comment: It transforms the point (pt) by the matrix that's the inverse of the screen CTM.

Comment: I'm confused with this too. I needed to convert points between two SVG elements. 
Finally I managed to hack something, might be suboptimal, but might help: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/svg-coordinates?file=index.ts

Comment: Here is a an article that miught help https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-translate-from-dom-to-svg-coordinates-and-back-again/